# How to find any list value in a dictionary

Tags: python

In my python project, I have a variable called "Dictionary" that is a dictionary of various string keys with integer values.

I also have a variable that is a list containing lots and lots of strings.

I would like my code to compare the strings in the list with the keys in the dictionary and, if one matches, assign the value of said key to a variable.

**Extra Information**: The input here is a variable called `listforwiki` which is a list of names formatted like so:

`['content','content','content',]` and so on for approx 300 strings.

This then runs through a Wikipedia API query, getting a synopsis of the bio for each string, and assigning this to `temp`.

This `temp` string is then split into a list of multiple strings by `.split()` and assigned to the variable `tempstring`

The expected output is the value from the dictionary. This is an integer.

All I want the code to do is compare the strings in the list `tempstring` with the values in the dictionary and, if there is a match, assign the complimentary key of said value in the dictionary to the variable `label`

Hope that clears everything up. Below, is the code I have so far.

```
try:
    for i in listforwiki:
        temp = wikipedia.summary(i)
        tempstring = temp.split()
        if tempstring in dictionary:
            label = dictionary[str(tempstring)]
except:
    pass
```

it simply DOES NOT WORK

I have no clue how to fix this, so if anyone could help I'd be really grateful.

N.B, the `label` variable is going to be assigned to an object parameter where it will need to be an integer, I'm only making it a string currently as the next line of code under `label = dictionary[str(tempstring)]` was `print(label)`, purely for troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Please add more information

Comment: `tempstring = temp.split()` split produces a list, so `tempstring` will be a list, so `if tempstring in dictionary` will never be true.

Comment: We’ll need the inputs and expected output please.

Comment: Please don't post solutions into questions. If you really want, you can post an answer

Answer (score 1):

The function split() returns an array of string as you can see here https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split so actually `tempstring` is a list of strings. What you should do is to iterate over `tempstring` and check if each string is in `dictionary`.

Comment: Okay, I think I get what you mean. How would you go about doing thus?

Comment: `for word in tempsrting: if word in dictionary: ...` @OliverFitzgerald

Comment: Aha it works! You are amazing @Tomerikoo and. See Update above for working code

Comment: @Sine1 couldnt tag you in post above, but you are equally amazing!